# Распределение фактора

Tags: r

Имеется вектор с `ip` адресами. Необходимо узнать распределение адресов. Пробовал работать с `factor()`, но результата я не достиг.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может помочь решить данную задачу?

**Ввод:**

```
x <- c("1.3.43.33", "2.2.43.33", "1.3.43.33", "66.3.43.33")
```

**Вывод:**

```
"1.3.43.33" - 2 ; "2.2.43.33" - 1 ; "3.3.43.33" - 1
```

Есть ли возможность вывести это в виде гистограммы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря что понимать под словом "гистограмма". О распределении тут говорить не приходится, но если есть необходимость отобразить, сколько раз каждый из IP адресов встречается во входной последовательности - то как-то вот так:

```
x <- c("1.3.43.33", "2.2.43.33", "1.3.43.33", "66.3.43.33")
barplot(table(x))
```